# DNX Core 5.0 JwtSecurityTokenHandler "IDX10640: Algorithm is not supported: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256'"

Tags: c#, json, jwt, adal

I'm trying to implement JWT tokens but keep running into the following exception: IDX10640: Algorithm is not supported: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256' when trying to write the token to compact json string.

```
const string issuer = "issuer";
const string audience = "audience";
byte[] keyForHmacSha256 = new byte[32];
new Random().NextBytes(keyForHmacSha256);

var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("deviceId", "12") };
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var expires = now.AddHours(1);
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
    new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyForHmacSha256), 
    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, audience, claims, now, expires, signingCredentials);
return _tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

Any ideas on solving this?

**Update 1:**

The error above occurs with "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.0.0-beta7-208241120"

**Update 2:**

Updated code

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue.  Are you using the `5.0.0-beta7-208241120` version of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` library?

Comment: Yes, good to hear I am not the only one...

Comment: 1) Why would you create a cryptographic key using `System.Random`? 2) a 128 byte key makes no sense. Did you want a 128 bit key (16 bytes)? 256 bits / 32 bytes would be a sane choice as well. 3) Using local time is pretty weird as well.

Comment: 1) I wrote that just to simplify the code section
2) Error also occurs with 128/256 bit key
3) Fixed

Comment: See Brent's answer below and this ticket for status: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have support for symmetric keys right now. Hope to get that in soon.

Answer (score 3):

Support will be in the RC2 release.
Tested with the nightly nuget packages from http://myget.org/gallery/azureadwebstacknightly

Only slight code changes needed to get everything to work

```
const string issuer = "issuer";
const string audience = "audience";
var keyForHmacSha256 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<tokenSecret>");
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyForHmacSha256);
var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("deviceId", "12") };
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var expires = now.AddHours(1);
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA256);

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(issuer, audience, claims, now, expires, signingCredentials);
return _tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

Validating the token can be done with the next bit of code

```
SecurityToken securityToken;
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    RequireExpirationTime = true,
    ValidateSignature = true,
    ValidAudience = audience,
    ValidIssuer = issuer,
    IssuerSigningKey = key,
    RequireSignedTokens = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true               
};

tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);
```